# Caching all dependencies in Docker image that has jetty:run in CMD

Tags: docker, maven, dockerfile

I'm trying to alter Dockerfile ending with:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["mvn", "clean", "jetty:run"]
```

to make it download all the Maven dependencies into the image, not when you run a container.

I added:

```
RUN mvn dependency:go-offline
```

It downloaded a lot of dependencies during build, but not all required to call `jetty:run`.
Because when alter the ENTRYPOINT

```
ENTRYPOINT ["mvn", "-o", "jetty:run"]
```

it fails when you run image:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:8.1.16.v20140903:run (default-cli) on project LODE: Execution default-cli of goal org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:8.1.16.v20140903:run failed: Plugin org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:8.1.16.v20140903 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Cannot access central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) in offline mode and the artifact org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.1 has not been downloaded from it before. -> [Help 1]
```

Can you somehow tell `go-offline` that you want to cache all the dependencies required to run a specific target (in this case `jetty:run`)? Maybe I can solve my main problem in any other way (it's actually not Docker-specific, but I wanted to show the motivation behind it)?

The project I'm altering is: https://github.com/essepuntato/LODE